# login from one domain and after that getting facebook object in another domain using php sdk 3.1.1

Tags: facebook, cross-domain, facebook-php-sdk

I am logining in and making the authentication processes from one domain (localhost)

```
$config = array(
    appId'  => $APP_ID,
    'secret' => $APP_SECRET
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$currentUserId = $facebook->getUser();
```

This works fine and i get an Access Token and a user id.
After that. from the browser i am making a post action to a php file on a remote domain
in the remote php i use the same code the same APP_ID and the same APP_SECRET

```
$config = array(
   'appId'  => $APP_ID,
   'secret' => $APP_SECRET
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$currentUserId = $facebook->getUser();
```

this does not! work and get $currentUserId = 0
and that is my problem

I can use (but dont want to):

```
 $facebook->setAccessToken($at);
```

with the acsess token from that i got  form the localhost domain it does work and i get the user id

In older sdk 2.0 I have seen this function setBaseDomain
Is there a way i can use it in 3.1.1?

Answer (score 2):

here's what I do - so when you make the request to the other domain pass along the access_token when you make the API call do something like this -

```
$config = array(
   'appId'  => $APP_ID,
   'secret' => $APP_SECRET
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$args['access_token'] = $_POST['token'] // or $_GET[];
$me = $facebook->api('/me', 'get', $args);
print_r($me);
```

So what that does then is say to FB I know the request is coming from a different server, but I have a valid token, please accept this sacrifice to mark zuckerberg and let me do things. It will accept and you're free to do as you please :)

Comment: Thanks. It does work buy I dont want to pass the acsess token. Is there a way to do that? I beleive cookies are responsible for that buy I dont know how to manipulate them. If its not possible this is also an a good answer

Comment: Facebook requires the token, if you're going to login from another domain than the original domain the user was at you will need the access token.